# How to get list of rows using a session list in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I my project i have a session variable that variable contains list of recently accessed values.With help of these values i need to get data from database.For this i wrote a storedprocedure with single parameter(@myparam) but its giving only one row from table.
How can get  list of rows from table using session list for storedprocedure?

Comment: It is not clear - what exactly you need, give an example

Comment: I am passig session list to my storedproc to get the rows from a table example:paramaters.Add(getParam("@recentAssetList", DbType.AnsiString, recentAssetList));return executeDataset("xp_ListRecentAssets", paramaters); in this "recentAssetList" contains list of values which are getting from session

Comment: Still not clear - you asking HOW to return a resultset from sp - as far as I see - you already call something like executeDataset - which as I assume - will return a table(s) to you

Comment: paramaters.Add(getParam("@recentAssetList", DbType.AnsiString, recentAssetList));return executeDataset("xp_ListRecentAssets", paramaters); in this "recentAssetList" contains {@recentAssetList=1,2,3,4,5,...} values then how can i create a procedure to get specified rows in a table

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, try this

```
CREATE function [dbo].[csv2tbl](@list nvarchar(max), @delimiter nvarchar(10))
returns @res table ([index] int PRIMARY KEY, col nvarchar(max))
AS BEGIN
with tbl_for_csv as
(
select 0 as [index] ,left(@list + @delimiter+@delimiter,charindex(@delimiter,@list + @delimiter+@delimiter) -1)as col,
right(@list + @delimiter+@delimiter,len(@list + @delimiter+@delimiter) - charindex(@delimiter,@list + @delimiter+@delimiter)) as Str
union all
select [index]+1, left(Str,charindex(@delimiter,Str) - 1)as Col,
right(Str,len(Str) - charindex(@delimiter,Str)) from tbl_for_csv
where len(right(Str,len(Str) - charindex(@delimiter,Str))) > 0
)
INSERT @res
select [index], col from tbl_for_csv option (MAXRECURSION 0);
return;
END
GO
SELECT * 
from YourTable
JOIN [dbo].[csv2tbl](@recentAssetList, ',') x ON x.col = yourtable.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i want stored procedure below is my code :recentAssetList = SessionData.RecentAssetList;(Ex: recentAssetList=1,2,3,4..)grdRecentAssetList.DataSource = DataAccess.ListRecentAssets(recentAssetList); grdRecentAssetList.DataBind(); in DataAccess class:public static DataSet ListRecentAssets(string recentAssetList) { try { ArrayList paramaters = getParamArray(); paramaters.Add(getParam("@recentAssetList", DbType.AnsiString, recentAssetList));return executeDataset("xp_ListRecentAssets", paramaters); }